# Como fazer interpolação linear no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um data.frame com 3 colunas: `YEAR`, `COHORT` e `Income`. Gostaria de fazer uma interpolação linear entre os valores de 1960 e de 1980 para definir os valores de 1970.

- Para o `COHORT = 5`, gostaria de fazer a interpolação entre os valores de renda do `COHORT 6` em 1960 e `COHORT 4` em 1980.
- Para o `COHORT = 6`, gostaria de fazer a interpolação entre os valores de renda do `COHORT 7` em 1960 e `COHORT 5` em 1980.
- Para o `COHORT = 7`, gostaria de fazer a interpolação entre os valores de renda do `COHORT 8` em 1960 e `COHORT 6` em 1980.

Meu `dput()`:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(1960, 1960, 1960, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1991, 1991, 1991, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2010, 2010
), COHORT = c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3), Income = c(915.724030772489, 1096.65213496088, 1091.86180401191, 
10658.0375195084, 12086.2816151274, 11935.8566030943, 1982.21058735071, 
2643.80498840172, 2678.68985776785, 1477.22485149727, 2110.03451057428, 
2195.96801801857, 1571.29380242384, 2233.01644287855, 2598.10210278486, 
1773.24017405619, 2224.76855916153, 2449.47650046232)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), groups = structure(list(YEAR = c(1960, 1970, 1980, 1991, 
2000, 2010), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 
    16:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
+------+--------+------------+
| YEAR | COHORT |   Income   |
+------+--------+------------+
| 1960 |      6 |    915.724 |
| 1960 |      7 |   1096.652 |
| 1960 |      8 |   1091.862 |
| 1970 |      5 |  10658.038 |
| 1970 |      6 |  12086.282 |
| 1970 |      7 |  11935.857 |
| 1980 |      4 |   1982.211 |
| 1980 |      5 |   2643.805 |
| 1980 |      6 |   2678.690 |
| 1991 |      3 |   1477.225 |
| 1991 |      4 |   2110.035 |
| 1991 |      5 |   2195.968 |
| 2000 |      2 |   1571.294 |
| 2000 |      3 |   2233.016 |
| 2000 |      4 |   2598.102 |
| 2010 |      1 |   1773.240 |
| 2010 |      2 |   2224.769 |
| 2010 |      3 |   2449.477 |
+------+--------+------------+
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso pelo `R`? Tentei usar a função `approxfun()`, mas não deu certo.

Comment: mas na sua tabela existe os valores de 1970, vc tem certeza que precisa de fazer interpolação ?? geralmente vc usa interpolação para encontrar um ponto desconhecido entre dois pontos/períodos, ,os períodos dados por você já estão na sua tabela

Comment: Preciso sin! Os valores de renda para 1970 na minha base estão errados, por isso a necessidade de interpolar.

Comment: então vc tá me dizendo que os valores de 1970 da sua tabela estão totalmente errados ? eita rsrs

Comment: Sim, você pode verificar que o `COHORT 6` em 1960 tem renda de 915, para 1970 esse valor sobe para 12.086, e em 1980 retorna para 2.678.

Comment: [Talvez seja relevante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023709/what-can-r-do-about-a-messy-data-format) para a forma como os dados estão na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que vc me passou é possível aplicar a equação da interpolação linear diretamente:

```
y = y1 + ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (y2 - y1)
```

Baseado no seu primeiro caso:

> Para o `COHORT = 5`, gostaria de fazer a interpolação entre os valores de renda do `COHORT 6` em 1960 e `COHORT 4` em 1980.

onde:

```
y1 = 915.724 (valor de cohort 6 de 1960)
x = 1970 (ano de interesse)
x1 = 1960 (ano do valor de y1)
x2 = 1980 (ano do cohort 4)
y2 = 1982.211 (valor de cohort 4)
```

Aplicando:

```
915.724 + ((1970 - 1960) / (1980 - 1960)) * (1982.211 - 915.724)
```

Resultado:

```
1448.968
```

Então para o `ano de 1970 cohort 5` vc terá `1448.968` como resultado da interpolação entre os pontos de interesse. Aplique a mesma equação e lógica para os outros pontos.

**EDIT**

Só por curiosidade eu fui ler a documentação da função [approxfun](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/approxfun) e realmente ela faz a Interpolação Linear, seguindo a mesma lógica demonstrada acima, vamos a um exemplo básico e prático de como usar essa função do `R`, vou criar um vetor com dois anos 1960 e 1980:

```
x <- c(1960, 1980)
```

Criando outro vetor com os valores respectivos dos anos de 1960 e 1980:

```
y <- c(915.724, 1982.211)
```

Aplicando a interpolação linear utilizando a função nativa do `R(approxfun)`

```
interpolado <- approxfun(x,y)
```

No caso acima o `R` irá retornar uma função com a interpolação dos pontos definidos, então para saber qual seria o valor de 1970, vc só precisa fazer agora:

```
interpolado(1970)
```

E o resultado foi `1448.968` ..... BINGOOO o mesmo resultado da equação que mostrei acima de como fazer sem ajuda de funções nativas

Matemática é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

huahuahua boa sorte!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 3):

Creio que o problema tem mais a ver com regressão que com interpolação. Se assim for, um modelo de regressão linear será

```
fit <- lm(Income ~ ., data = dados, subset = YEAR %in% c(1960, 1980))
new <- data.frame(YEAR = 1970, COHORT = 5:7)
predict(fit, newdata = new)
#       1        2        3 
#1516.670 1734.824 1952.978
```

---

Para resolver o problema por interpolação linear, o código seguinte dá os valores para cada `COHORT`.

```
dados2 <- subset(dados, YEAR %in% c(1960, 1980))
f <- with(dados2, ave(YEAR, YEAR, FUN = seq_along))
res <- by(dados2[-1], f, FUN = function(X){
  approx(X[["COHORT"]], X[["Income"]], xout = mean(X[["COHORT"]]))
})
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
names(res) <- names(dados2[-1])

res
#  COHORT   Income
#1      5 1448.967
#2      6 1870.228
#3      7 1885.276
```

---

Também interpolação linear, mais simples. Usa o facto de o novo ponto ser a média dos dois valores conhecidos. Ver a [resposta do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516414/82237).

```
dados2 <- subset(dados, YEAR %in% c(1960, 1980))
f <- with(dados2, ave(YEAR, YEAR, FUN = seq_along))
tapply(dados2$Income, f, mean)
#       1        2        3 
#1448.967 1870.228 1885.276
```

---

Remover variáveis que já não são precisas.

```
rm(f, dados2)
```

---

### Gráfico

Gráfico de ambas as soluções.

```
plot(Income ~ YEAR, dados2)
points(rep(1970, 3), predict(fit, newdata = new), pch = 3, col = "blue")
points(rep(1970, 3), res$Income, pch = 4, col = "blue")
legend("topleft", legend = c("Regressão", "Interpolação"), pch = 3:4, col = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Dados

```
x <- "+------+--------+------------+
| YEAR | COHORT |   Income   |
+------+--------+------------+
| 1960 |      6 |    915.724 |
| 1960 |      7 |   1096.652 |
| 1960 |      8 |   1091.862 |
| 1970 |      5 |  10658.038 |
| 1970 |      6 |  12086.282 |
| 1970 |      7 |  11935.857 |
| 1980 |      4 |   1982.211 |
| 1980 |      5 |   2643.805 |
| 1980 |      6 |   2678.690 |
| 1991 |      3 |   1477.225 |
| 1991 |      4 |   2110.035 |
| 1991 |      5 |   2195.968 |
| 2000 |      2 |   1571.294 |
| 2000 |      3 |   2233.016 |
| 2000 |      4 |   2598.102 |
| 2010 |      1 |   1773.240 |
| 2010 |      2 |   2224.769 |
| 2010 |      3 |   2449.477 |
+------+--------+------------+
"
dados <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE, sep = "|", comment.char = "+")
dados <- dados[-c(1, ncol(dados))]
str(dados)
head(dados)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução!

Answer (score 3):

Interpolação é usada para coordenadas xy, não é exatamente o seu caso; basta fazer a média entre `YEAR-10 & COHORT+1` e `YEAR+10 & COHORT-1`:

```
ano <- 1970
for (c in dados[dados$YEAR == ano, "COHORT"]) {
  dados[dados$YEAR == ano & dados$COHORT == c, "Income"] <-
    mean(c(dados[dados$YEAR == ano-10 & dados$COHORT == c+1, "Income"],
           dados[dados$YEAR == ano+10 & dados$COHORT == c-1, "Income"]))
}

subset(dados, YEAR == 1970)
#>   YEAR COHORT   Income
#> 4 1970      5 1448.967
#> 5 1970      6 1870.229
#> 6 1970      7 1885.276
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução!